# Bash scripting, collecting information in collection

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, scripting

I am new to the world of bash scripting. I am trying to do a simple task. trying to list all the logged in users and the process they are using.

When I do `$(who)`, I get the following:

```
user1   console  Nov 19 21:08
user1   ttys010  Nov 28 09:32
```

I am expecting my script to output something like:

```
user1:console
user1:ttys010
```

For this, I am trying to do the following.

```
userlist=$(who)
for users in $userlist
do
    echo $users
done
```

The output I was expecting was the $users would have a the following value:

```
$users[0] : user1   console  Nov 19 21:08 (so that I could use 'cut' command to get what I wanted)
```

Instead the real value for $users when I run this command is  :

```
$users[0] = user1
$users[1] = console
$users[2] = Nov
```

Will be grateful if someone could point me on how to achieve.
This is not about getting the logged in users, but more about learning to work with inputs and loops.

Answer (score 2):

Using `read` with a `while` loop:

```
userlist=$(who)
while read user line other; do
  echo "$user":"$line";
done <<< "$userlist"
```

For each line:

- `user` and `line` are set to the first two strings of the `who` command (the `other` variable is for the rest of the line, not used here).
- the variables are echoed with a `:` delimiter.

Or with `cut`:

```
who | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1,2 --output-delimiter=$':'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very clear in my head now, how this works.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the `for` loop is:

```
for NAME [ [in [WORDS ...] ] ; ] do COMMANDS; done
```

where `WORDS` are [`$IFS`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF)-separated strings.

The expression `userlist=$(who)` assigns the output of `who` command to `userlist` variable. If the `$userlist` variable is not enclosed in double quotes, it is expanded to the words separated by the `$IFS` characters (newlines and spaces, in particular).

Thus, the following loop iterates all the words within `$userlist` string (the output of `who` command).

```
for word in $userlist; do echo "$word"; done
```

In order to capture the first two fields of the output, you can use `AWK` tool as follows:

```
who | awk '{print $1 ":" $2}'
```

The variables `$1` and `$2` refer to the first and the second fields in the record.

The records are separated by the characters specified in AWK's `RS` (record separator) [built-in variable](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_built_in_variables.htm). `RS` equals to single newline character by default.

Similarly, `FS` built-in variable specifies the field separator(s). Its default value is space.

Comment: Thanks Ruslan for the detailed answer and explanation. This has given me an insight into how these things work. Being new to the world of scripting, I really appreciate this